# Adding Annotation to Apache Fop

Tags: apache, xslt, pdf, annotations, apache-fop

I am rendering  a PDF using **Apache Fop**. I am making XSLT templates which I used to convert xml to PDF. I want to put annotation in the output PDF using **Apache Fop**. 
**I have been searching and it says iText has support for adding annotation to pdf.**

*Is it possible to add annotation in Apache Fop?*

Comment: With annotation, you mean comments you can make in pdf files?

Comment: yes @RobertG , I would like to add comments in my pdf files, pdf files were rendered using apache fop, is it possible to add comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iText DOES have support for adding annotations to PDF documents. We use that in our products.
You can do the following:

- Use an existing PDF, for example one that has been created with Apache FOP. You would need to write a Java program that adds annotations to this PDF document.
- Create the PDF and annotations programmatically using the iText API from XML data (without involving Apache FOP).

I'm not sure though whether this is what you want. iText is no replacement for a GUI application.

Comment: thank you @Susanne,Actually, what I want is that I want to add annotation directly using Apache Fop, But I guess it is not possible with Apache Fop. Bu