# XSLT 1.0 + Apache FOP Is there a way to include "not printable" content?

Tags: xslt, pdf, xslt-1.0, apache-fop

I want to output some content that is shown in a pdf reader but not in a printed document.

The problem is that i need to print over a pre-printed page, so I want to "show" all in the screen but not the layout when it's sent to printer (as the page already have a pre-printed layout).

Comment: Do you mean annotations or comments in PDF? Then, this might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617745/adding-annotation-to-apache-fop

Comment: No, i mean like drawing a line, table, text or any item being visible in pdf reader but no in printed paper

Comment: I don't think Apache FOP is capable of that. (Does the PDF standard support it in the first place?) It might be easier to produce two PDF files - one for display and the other one for print.

Comment: I don't really know, but that aproach is not possible sadly

Comment: Annotations, buttons and layers support "visible but not printable" settings; common page content objects do not.